# How can I know when I need to dispose of a disposable in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java2

Trying to understand RxJava here. We have this code:

```
public void notifyNewOwnersSynced() {
      OrgTreeType orgTreeType = getOrgTreeType();
      new OrgTreeQuerier().queryOrgUserIds().byOrgTreeType(orgTreeType).executeAsync()
              .map(opt -> opt.isPresent() ? opt.get() : new HashSet<String>(0))
              .subscribe(
                      this::onNewOrgUserIds,
                      e -> Log.exception(new Exception("Unable to update selected id filter for type " + orgTreeType, e))
              );

  }


private void onNewOrgUserIds(@NonNull Set<String> allIds) {
      synchronized (mLock) {
          for (String id : allIds) {
              if (!mPreviousAllIds.contains(id)) {
                  mSelectedIDs.add(id);
              }
          }

          Set<String> idsNoLongerInHierarchy = new HashSet<>(); //Because we can't remove while we are iterating.
          for (String selectedId : mSelectedIDs) {
              //If there is a selected ID not in the new hierarchy...
              if (!allIds.contains(selectedId)) {
                  //Plan to remove it.
                  idsNoLongerInHierarchy.add(selectedId);
              }
          }
          mSelectedIDs.removeAll(idsNoLongerInHierarchy);
          mPreviousAllIds = allIds;

      }

      mSaveListener.saveChangesAndPostFilterChangedEvent();
      postSelectedIdsChangedEvent();
  }
```

We have two lint warnings showing up on it:  `The result of subscribe is not used.` and `Result of single.subscribe() is ignored`

This is in a class that is used by our UI(Fragments) to keep track of what users have been selected.

But on a larger scale we have a lot of spots in our code that use Rx like this to do something in the background (map something, network call, save data to the DB)  and we don't every use the result.

Can I safely suppress these errors?  or do I need to add handling for the Disposables?

How can I know when I need to dispose of a disposable?

Answer (score 1):

Although not a comprehensive list of cases, I think I can point out some that I've faced during my career and might help you out.

The most common scenario I faced was when we make network calls that take too long and the app is put in the background. If not disposed, the result of the network will be forwarded to the subscriber. This is not really the issue. The problem is that usually the subscriber wants to change something UI related, which crashes the app. In this case, you dispose because you are no longer interested in receiving these events.

There are cases where the way the subscriber handles the result wouldn't be problematic, but the IDE has no way to know this and hence it warns you all the time.

I'm sure there are tons of other reasons why disposing should be handled - i.e., when observables acquire resources when subscribed and release them once unsubscribed from. So in general I guess it's good to handle the disposables. I only ever kept a disposable undisposed when I wanted to keep downloading files in the background and to be honest with you, I'm not even sure if this is a good practise.

Adding to this, if an observable or any of the other flavored observables (single, maybe, etc.) terminates, then it's disposed automatically.